# Why does the following c code work in turbo c and not in devc++?

Tags: c, string, pointers, compiler-specific

I have the following piece of code:

```
char *str;
gets(str);
```

Now it works in turbo c but fails to in devc.

I have to add the following in order to make it work in devC++.

```
char *str = malloc(5);
```

Can anyone explain, why is it so?

Also, which one is authentic and a more correct form of coding.

Comment: 1) don't use `gets()` 2) undefined behaviour on unallocated string.

Comment: It's a mystery why it "works in Turbo C" because there is no memory allocated to the pointer.

Comment: you might want to read up on [`gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets).

Comment: When you define the pointer variable `str`, where does it point? It needs to *point* to some memory where `gets` (***really*** don't use it) write the characters it reads.

Answer (score 0):

that

```
char *str;
gets(str);
```

just *cannot* be right. `str` is not initialized, and `gets` recieves the pointer by value so it cannot allocate it internally. You're just lucky/unlucky with *undefined behaviour*.

> which one is authentic and a more correct form of coding ?

None of the above. *don't use `gets`*. It's unsafe because you cannot limit the input size. Use `fgets` with specified size (and an allocated buffer of course!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
char buffer[20];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); // reads at most 19 chars + null-termination
```

or `scanf` with size limit (note the -1): `scanf("%19s",buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

```
gets(str);
```

It shouldnt work even in turbo c++ because you have not allocated the space to str.
correct way

```
 str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length+1));
```